# How to best pickle/unpickle in class hierarchies if parent and child class instances are pickled

Tags: python, persistence, pickle

Assume I have a class A and a class B that is derived from A. I want to pickle/unpickle an instance of class B. Both A and B define the __getstate__/__setstate__ methods (Let's assume A and B are complex, which makes the use of __getstate__ and __setstate__ necessary). How should B call the __getstate__/__setstate__ methods of A? My current, but perhaps not the 'right' approach:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__():
        self.value=1
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.value)
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        (self.value) = state

class B(A):
    def __init__():
        self.anothervalue=2
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (A.__getstate__(self), self.anothervalue)
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        superstate, self.anothervalue = state
        A.__setstate__(self, superstate)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `super(B,self)` to get instances of `B` to call the methods of `A`:

```
import cPickle
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value=1
    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.value
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.value = state

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self).__init__()
        self.anothervalue=2
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (super(B,self).__getstate__(), self.anothervalue)
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        superstate, self.anothervalue = state
        super(B,self).__setstate__(superstate)

b=B()
with open('a','w') as f:
    cPickle.dump(b,f)


with open('a','r') as f:
    c=cPickle.load(f)
print(b.value)
print(b.anothervalue)
```

See [this article](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#method-resolution-order) for more info on method resolution order (MRO) and super.